# what is the difference between "firebase login" and "firebase login:ci"?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When i login with **firebase login:ci** it returns a token, but when I login with **firebase login** it does not. What is the difference in other functionality?
Deployment works as expected using **firebase login** but not with **firebase login:ci** and its token.

Comment: `firebase login` starts an interactive login flow that opens a browser tab, while `firebase login:ci` starts a flow that doesn't popup a browser and that can be used on so-called headless systems. But instead of asking us for the difference between the two commands, I recommend showing the command you expected to work and what happened instead.

Comment: With both the commands the browser gets popped up. The only difference I can see is **firebase login:ci** gives a token but **firebase login** wont.

Answer (score 1):

Posting Frank's comment as community wiki for visibility.

`firebase login` starts an interactive login flow that opens a browser tab, while `firebase login:ci` starts a flow that doesn't popup a browser and that can be used on so-called headless systems. But instead of asking us for the difference between the two commands, I recommend showing the command you expected to work and what happened instead